# When should you NOT use the asterisk (*) when declaring a variable in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have just started learning objective c and the asterisk is giving me some trouble. As I look through sample code, sometime it is used when declaring a variable and sometimes it is not. What are the "rules" for when it should be used. I thought it had something to do with the data type of the variable. (asterisk needed for object data types, not needed for simple data types like int) However, I have seen object data types such as CGPoint declared without the asterisk as well? Is there a definitive answer or does it have to do with how and what you use the variable for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What are the "rules" for when it should be used.

You use the asterisk to declare a pointer.

For a Cocoa object, you're always declaring a pointer, so you always use an asterisk. You can't put the object itself into the variable; you always handle a pointer to the object.

For other things, it depends on whether the variable will contain the object (in the C sense) or a pointer to the object-somewhere-else. If the variable should contain the object, then you don't declare it with an asterisk, because you're not putting a pointer in it. If it should contain a pointer, then you do declare it with an asterisk.

You can even have a pointer to a pointer; as you might expect, this involves multiple asterisks. For example, `NSRect **` is a pointer to a pointer to an NSRect (which is a structure, not a Cocoa object).

> I thought it had something to do with the data type of the variable. (asterisk needed for object data types, not needed for simple data types like int)

Sort of. The asterisk is needed for Cocoa objects because you can only handle pointers to Cocoa objects, never the objects themselves. But the rules for declaration are no different for Cocoa objects; they are exactly the same. You use the asterisk when you want a pointer variable; you don't when you want a non-pointer variable.

The only exception, the only difference for Cocoa objects from the usual rules, is that you are not allowed to declare a variable holding the object itself. That's why you never see a variable holding a Cocoa object instead of a pointer to one: the compiler won't allow it.

> However, I have seen object data types such as CGPoint declared without the asterisk as well?

CGPoint is a structure, not a Cocoa object. As such, you can declare a variable that holds a CGPoint and not a pointer to one somewhere else.

Comment: A (largely historical) note: Not all flavors of Objective-C required 'pointers to objects'.  Some even allowed you to create objects on the stack in the form of `NSObject object;`.

Comment: Largely, perhaps, but not entirely historical: On GNUstep, IIRC, you still can declare an object on the stack.

Comment: Err, no.  GNUstep is, for all practical purposes, a shared library- essentially a clone of AppKit.framework and Foundation.framework (ie, the `OpenStep` specification).  GNUstep has their own runtime as well (libobjc). "Classic" Objective-C, which I'd define as up to Apples Objective-C 1.0, is an amazing language.  It provides a few simple primitives and little dogma on how you should use them, which is no surprise considering its heritage.  Most consider it to be a "strict superset" of the C it is layered on top of.  Not so with ObjC2 (ie, GC and `void *` pointers, for example).

Answer (score 7):

I think you should read a bit on C programming first. Objective-C is a superset of C.
The reason why you don't use * for declaring CGPoint is because CGPoint is a struct, take a look in the CGGeometry.h header file.

Comment: This is the real key.  For the type in question, go to the .h file where it is defined, and look to see whether it is a struct or a class.  If it's a class, you need the *; if it's a struct, you do not need it for normal use, though you can if you want -- but that's a more advanced topic.

Comment: Yes, this is my fault. I falsely assumed CGPoint was an object data type and this caused almost all of the confusion on my point. Is there something specific I should look for in the .h file to know if it is and object. Is it as easy as looking what the superclass is?

Answer (score 6):

The asterisk indicates the variable is a pointer to a datatype.

You should look into [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)) for more information. They are a very important and fundamental aspect of programming.

Comment: I understand it means it is a pointer. But my questions is when you should or shouldn't the pointer be used?

Comment: It depends entirely on the situation. You need to use heap-allocated memory if you want to return a value from a function, for example, since otherwise it would be reclaimed when the function exits. Pointers are also required for referencing arrays. It's not an easy question to answer, Jason. Stack allocation is useful since you don't have to worry as much about memory, but just using stack-allocated objects doesn't mean you don't need to deal with pointers.  But basically if your type is small and short-lived, don't bother with pointers. If it's large or long-lived, use pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You use a `*` when the variable type is a class.

An example may help.

```
NSNumber *number;
NSInteger integer;
```

The `NSNumber` variable type is a class while `NSInteger` is just another name for a normal C-type `int`. As you can see here, the compiler replaces every occurrence of `NSInteger` with `int`:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
  typedef long NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
  typedef int NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

---

Further, you cannot declare an instance of a class(an object), like `NSNumber`, without using a pointer(thus you use a `*`). The reason for this is that when you `alloc` an instance of a class as an object a memory address is returned. A pointer is a type of variable that specifically refers to a memory location. For example:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber alloc];
```

Here `number`'s numeric value would be a memory location like `0x19a30c0`. You could operate on it by adding and subtracting, like an `int`. The key purpose of declaring it as a `NSNumber` pointer is so the compiler can help the coder verify that the class has certain methods or to access known properties.

---

One last example:

```
NSInteger integer = [NSNumber alloc];
```

What would the value of `integer` be? In our example, it would be 0x19a30c0. With this you could actually still access the newly allocated `NSNumber` object via `[integer someMethod]`. The compiler would give you a warning, though. More over:

```
integer += 4;
```

This would affect the numeric value `0x19a30c0` by adding 4 to it and making it `0x19a30c4`.

---

Look at this Wikipedia article on [C/C++ pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)#C_and_C.2B.2B) for some more examples of how, when, and why to use an `*` operator.

Comment: Speaking to your question about CGPoint, you should know that CGPoint is NOT a class. It is a structure. Thus, you can have static, non-mutable CGPoints allocated on compiling the code.

On the flip side, if you dynamically allocated a CGPoint during run-time, you would use a CGPoint pointer(ie: CGPoint *cgPointer) to reference the variable in memory.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got the rule figured out: asterisk for pointer, no asterisk otherwise. The trouble is, there is no rule for determining whether or not something like CGPoint will require a pointer without looking at the header file. As Welbog said, the real distinction between when to use/not use a pointer is whether you're allocating on the heap or the stack, although most of the time you'll only need to determine whether you're working with an object (asterisk) or a primitive (no asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: you should **always** use the asterisk when using Objective-C objects.

The reason is that they can't be allocated on the stack, so you cannot do what you can do with structures like CGPoint.

The designers of Objective-C chose, I suppose, to make you always add that asterisk because they are pointers to memory like other C-pointers.