# Why no asterisk sign when creating instance of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString listOfNames = @"..."; // a long list of names
NSString name = @"Ward";
NSRange match = [listOfNames rangeOfString:name];
if (match.location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"No match found!");
    // Other actions to be taken
} else {
    NSLog(@"Match found!");
    // Other actions to be taken
}
```

Why don't the 1st, 2nd and third line of code use asterisk sign like this

```
NSString *listOfNames = @"..."; 
NSString *name = @"Ward";
NSRange *match = [listOfNames rangeOfString:name];
```

Comment: Have you actually tried compiling this code? You will likely find that it does not work. Btw, `NSRange` is not an Objective-C class so it does not in fact need the `*`.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172600/when-should-you-not-use-the-asterisk-when-declaring-a-variable-in-objective

Comment: Sorry it was the books error, no i did not try to run the code as i always assume the book to be correct. I'll try to run the code before asking any question next time. Sorry.

Comment: please share the book name and author, so that no-other learner end up learning from that book/author.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString listOfNames = @"..."; // a long list of names
NSString name = @"Ward";
NSRange match = [listOfNames rangeOfString:name];
```

First two lines are creating `NSString`'s objectect. `NSString` is a subclass of `NSObject`, and all `NSObject` and its subclass should have `*` (pointer sign associated with them).

While `NSRange` is a struct **not in the inheritance chain with `NSObject`**, hence no pointer sign is required, however under some situations you can make pointers to NSRange too.

**Your above code will give compiler errors.*

You need to use it as :

```
NSString *listOfNames = @"..."; // a long list of names
NSString *name = @"Ward";
NSRange match = [listOfNames rangeOfString:name];
```

Comment: Why don't NSRange need an asterisk?

Comment: if you wish you can create pointers of nsrange, but do you really need the pointer for that. Mostly you need the value directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSString* str = [NSString stringWithString:@"Blah..."];
```

Note the `*` after `NSString`. You're working objective C here so pointers to objects!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can't execute this code, if you execute this code you will get errors.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is what I normally see when try to do same. XCode automatically prompt you to add "*" before property name.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in Cocoa object, you're always declaring a pointer, so you always use an asterisk. You can't put the object itself into the variable; you always handle a pointer to the object.

for other objects
If the variable contain's the object, then you don't use an asterisk, because you're not putting a pointer in it. If it contain's a pointer, then you do declare it with an asterisk.

Comment: Wait a second you just said that we cannot put object itself into variable, but on the 2nd paragraph you said variable contains the object.