# Objective-C, why do I need to put this asterix here but not here

Tags: objective-c, pointers

My question is pretty simple, why do I need to put an asterix for NSString but not for NSInteger ?

```
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, world !"];
    NSInteger myInteger = 42;
```

Comment: You need to read lots of books first...

Comment: Start by reading Apples [Programming in Objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: because of difference between object and trivial types

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should you NOT use the asterisk (\*) when declaring a variable in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172600/when-should-you-not-use-the-asterisk-when-declaring-a-variable-in-objective)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a Cocoa object, you're always declaring a pointer, so you always use an asterisk. You can't put the object itself into the variable; you always handle a pointer to the object.

For other things, it depends on whether the variable will contain the object (in the C sense) or a pointer to the object-somewhere-else. If the variable should contain the object, then you don't declare it with an asterisk, because you're not putting a pointer in it. If it should contain a pointer, then you do declare it with an asterisk.

In C and Objective C, an int is a primitive data type. If you write int *, which means "a pointer to an int”.

There are few links which can help you to understand it very nicely.

Courtesy:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5293419/1865424

http://boredzo.org/pointers/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1173252/1865424

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps me a lot !!! May I ask you one last question ? What is the technical reason of this ? Why can't I put the object itself into the variable whereas I can do that for the int ?

Comment: See first of all you have to cleary understand how things work, So i suggest you to read http://boredzo.org/pointers/ ,It explains every thing you want to know about pointers. If after reading this your problem persist then you ask, I am happy to help you.

Comment: Ok, I'll read it thank you !

Comment: The main difference between primitives and objects is: Primitives are so small, they can be stored in the stack. Objects on the other hand may not fit in the stack, so a pointer (which fits in the stack) is used to point to the object's location in the heap where (theoretically) there is no size limit.

Answer (score 5):

NSInteger is a typedef of int, while NSString is a pointer to objects of class NSString.