# Considering typedef_NS_ENUM

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make my code more readable through `typedef NS_ENUM`. I have 3 cases. Please look at the code:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, drawCase) {
    drawCaseStart,
    drawCaseIn,
    drawCaseAfter
};


@interface DayGraphViewCircle ()

@property (nonatomic) drawCase *myCase;
```

Then:

```
-(void)choseDrawCase{

    switch (self.drawCases) {
        case 0:
            _myCase = drawCaseStart;
            break;

        case 1:
            _myCase = drawCaseInProcess;
            break;

        case 2:
            _myCase = drawCaseAfter;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In case 1 and 2 compiler highlight my code with yellow  Incompatible `integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'drawCase *' (aka 'enum drawCase *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')`

What i did wrong?

Comment: remove the * in drawCase. Please note that all integers/floats/doubles/Bools should be declared without *. Only vars that are object type should be declared with *

Comment: You've declared `myCase` as a pointer to a `drawCase`. Remove the `*` and the code will compile

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thank you, but i wonder why it does not highlight first case..

Comment: May be it is just a compiler bug.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri okay it works, thank you!

Comment: For more info pleaserefer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172600/when-should-you-not-use-the-asterisk-when-declaring-a-variable-in-objective

Comment: It doesn't highlight the first case because assigning `0` to a pointer is considered the same as assigning it `nil`

Comment: @dan good, thats make sense